# Unable to Insert Twilio Message Received Date/Time into MYSQL DB Table

Tags: mysql, twilio, phone-number

The field name is **msg_received** and the data type is **DATETIME**

When a Twilio sms message is received, the **msg_received** field is populated with **0000-00-00 00:00:00**

Being a complete newbie, I thought I got pretty far, but I am nit understanding this.

```
<?php
header("content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";

$MsgSid = $_REQUEST['MessageSid'];
$SmsSid = $_REQUEST['SmsSid'];
$MsgFrom = $_REQUEST['From'];
$MsgBody = $_REQUEST['Body'];

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="xxxxxxxx"; // Mysql username 
$password="xxxxxxx"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="xxxxxxx"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="xxxxxxx"; // Table name

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (msg_received, msg_MessageSid, msg_SmsSid, msg_From, msg_Body) VALUES ('CURRENT-TIMESTAMP', '$MsgRecd', '$MsgSid', '$SmsSid', '$MsgFrom', '$MsgBody')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: You're looking for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`, without the quotes.

Comment: That's the fix. Thank you so much. For future reference, if the value is defined, then it is not enclosed in quotes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by defined. Quotes denote a string *literal*. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` is a function that *returns* a string *value*.